# Why and what significance James Alexander McKenzie Fraser was called McDubh?

Tags: outlander

Did I miss any portion of Outlander that might explain why Jamie Fraser was called McDubh?

Is there any significance to being called "McDubh"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd lost track of his myriad names across the years, so I had to look this one up.

From [IndieWire - ‘Outlander’: Jamie Fraser’s Many Aliases From The Dunbonnet to Mac Dubh, Explained](https://www.indiewire.com/2017/10/outlander-jamie-fraser-nickname-alias-dunbonnet-macdubh-alexander-malcolm-1201885100/)

> **Mac Dubh**
>
> The show first introduces this name in Season 3, Episode 3, “All Debts Paid” when Jamie is in prison. It’s a name that reveals how well the other prisoners know him and mixes a nickname, lineage, and Gaelic all in one. Jamie’s father’s name was Brian (hence, why Claire names their daughter Brianna), and was known as Black Brian. Therefore, that makes Jamie the son of the Black One, or in Gaelic, Mac Dubh.

Comment: Not sure if they got this somehow mixed up in the show (or books), or if the article (and seemingly the Internet in general) did, but as far as I can tell, this doesn’t really work. _Mac Dubh_ means ‘black(-haired) son’, not ‘son of the black(-haired) one’; _dubh_ is an adjective describing _mac_. ‘Son of the Black(-haired) One’ is actually attested as a perfectly common Scottish surname: _MacDhuibh_ (Anglicised McDuff or just Duff), in which _Dhuibh_ is the genitive form of nominalised _dubh_ as expected. Since Jamie is a redhead, ‘Mac Dubh’ really doesn’t make sense at all.

Comment: Well, not that I know much about Gaelic or the novels at all, but as his father was called Brian Dubh, then 'son of a guy called Dubh' works for me. https://outlander.fandom.com/wiki/Brian_Fraser

Comment: The trouble is that for that to work, _Dubh_ needs to be in the genitive, and the genitive of _Dubh_ (as a name) is _Dhuibh_. _Mac Dubh_ doesn’t mean ‘son of [a guy called] Dubh’, it just means ’son Dubh’. It’s the same as how _MacDhòmhnaill_ (MacDonald) uses _Dhòmhnaill_ (genitive of _Dòmhnall_), _MacDhonnchaidh_ (MacConaughey, Donohue, etc.) uses _Dhonnchaidh_ (genitive of _Donnchadh_), etc.

Comment: Yup - as I said, I know nothing of Gaelic… nor enough English grammar to accurately distinguish a nominative from a genitive. It just goes right over my head, & probably 99.9% of the audience too.

Comment: The odd thing is that there’s plenty of actual Gaelic dialogue in the show, and though my Scottish isn’t very good (it’s Irish I’m focused on), what I’ve seen appears genuine enough. I know they had Gaelic consultants on the show as well, which is why I find this so surprising, because in Gaelic, it’s as glaring as changing ‘Black’s daughter’ to ‘black daughter’ in English.

Comment: Presumably the name comes from the books initially - it's a done deal then by the time it lands in the show. Most Brits would be familiar with the name, however spelled, as McDuff, even if all they can do is mis-quote Shakespeare, with the usual "Lead on Macduff".